# Python re.compile truncates the string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the following pattern

```
pattern = "campaigns.methods.campaign_methods:get_campaign:campaign_id:(?P<campaign_id>.+):as_admin:(?P<as_admin>.+):accesses_params:(?P<accesses_params>.+):x_company_id:(?P<x_company_id>.+):x_user_id:(?P<x_user_id>.+)"
```

**I use the following code:**

```
re_compile = re.compile("^" + pattern + "$", flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

**I expect the result:**

```
re.compile('^campaigns.methods.campaign_methods:get_campaign:campaign_id:(?P<campaign_id>.+):as_admin:(?P<as_admin>.+):accesses_params:(?P<accesses_params>.+):x_company_id:(?P<x_company_id>.+):x_user_id:(?P<x_user_id>.+)$', re.MULTILINE)
```

**As a result, I get:**

```
re.compile('^campaigns.methods.campaign_methods:get_campaign:campaign_id:(?P<campaign_id>.+):as_admin:(?P<as_admin>.+):accesses_params:(?P<accesses_params>.+):x_company_id:(?P<x_company_id>.+):x_user_id:(?P<x_us, re.MULTILINE)
```

**Full exemple code:**

```
import re

pattern = "campaigns.methods.campaign_methods:get_campaign:campaign_id:(?P<campaign_id>.+):as_admin:(?P<as_admin>.+):accesses_params:(?P<accesses_params>.+):x_company_id:(?P<x_company_id>.+):x_user_id:(?P<x_user_id>.+)"
re_compile = re.compile("^" + pattern + "$", flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(re_compile)
```

Please tell me what the problem may be

Comment: The question is hard to read, because the lines are so long. I think you might get answers quicker if you could squeeze it down to something minimal that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @TurePålsson The problem doesn't occur if the line is shorter. It's probably a limit on how much `__str__` of the regex is willing to display.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa that is, in fact, everything works correctly, just not everything is output to the console?

Comment: You call it a problem. Is it really a problem? In what way?

Comment: You can bypass the truncation of `__str__` by outputting the `pattern` attribute: `print(re_compile.pattern)`.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa It seems rather clear that they don't want fullmatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer by Piotr Siupa:

> The problem doesn't occur if the line is shorter. It's probably a limit on how much `__str__` of the regex is willing to display.